# Node.js driver for SqlAnywhere - Prepared statements exceeded

Tags: node.js, prepared-statement, sqlanywhere

I am using the node.js [driver](https://github.com/sqlanywhere/node-sqlanywhere) for SqlAnywhere.

I am getting the **"Resource governor for 'prepared statements' exceeded"** error.

Initially, I was executing my queries like this:

```
connection.exec(myQuery, myArgs, myCallback);
```

where `myQuery` would look like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM some_procedure(?, ?, ?);"
```

I then changed it to:

```
connection.exec(myQuery, myCallback);
```

with myQuery now looking like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM some_procedure(%s);"
```

and then formatting the query using `util.format` :

```
myQuery = util.format(query, args.join(','));
```

... but I still get the same error. Why is this happening?

How can I prevent the connection from creating a bunch of prepared statements?

Thanks!

Edit: I am aware that there is a limit of 50 (default value) prepared statements for a connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is a bug in the **sqlanywhere** api.
I checked their code and it seems that they don't drop the statement when you pass a callback to the query

```
if( callback_required ) {
    Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[cbfunc_arg]);
    baton->callback = Persistent<Function>::New( callback );

    int status;
    status = uv_queue_work( uv_default_loop(), req, executeWork, (uv_after_work_cb)executeAfter );
    assert(status == 0);

    return scope.Close( Undefined() );
    }
```

The stmt drop code is executed only after this callback if

```
if( baton->sqlany_stmt != NULL ) {
    api.sqlany_free_stmt( baton->sqlany_stmt );
    }
```

Anyway as work around I suggest you to create a `statement` for each query and then `drop` it after executed.

Also would be interesting to report this bug in their [github](https://github.com/sqlanywhere/node-sqlanywhere/blob/master/src/sqlanywhere.cpp).

Comment: Thank you, indeed creating a statement and then dropping it afterwards has solved my problem. I will report this bug on their github. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for reporting this problem. It has been fixed and a new version has been uploaded to npm and github.